# How many times should I add cityName to Bundle in Navigation Component with 4 fragments?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-bundle

I have implemented Navigation Component with 4 fragments:

```
F1 -> F2 -> F3 -> F4
```

To navigate from **F1 -> F2**, I use :

```
val bundle = bundleOf("cityName" to cityName)
findNavController().navigate(R.id.second_fragment, bundle)
```

Now, I want to propagate the "cityName" all the way to F4. Is it necessary to do the same thing also when navigation from **F2 -> F3** and **F3 -> F4**, or is it enough to do it only once, as I already did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use arguments, you need to propagate them from one fragment to another, because each fragment can have different set of arguments. You can improve this by using [Safe Args plugin](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args).

#### Alternative 1

In case of single activity it's easy to define [shared view model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) to control common ui parts of your app (app bar title, for example)

```kotlin
interface HostViewModel {
    
    val screenTitle: LiveData<String>

    fun setScreenTitle(title: String)
}
```

#### Alternative 2

You can create [nested graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs) for your flow (F1->...->F4) and tie [destination view model](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel) to it